# Prove that $\lim_ {x\to \infty}\min(|x-\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}|)=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

For $x\gt0$, let $f(x)$ be the minimum value of $|x-\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}|$ for all integers $m, n$. Then Prove that $$\lim_ {x\to \infty} f(x)= \; 0$$

---

I am completely stuck with this question, minimum value of modulus is zero that's fine, but how $f(x)$ will be zero when $x$ approaches to $\infty$. If I take $\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}$ to be some nearest value of  $x$ Then it takes $|\infty -\infty|$ form; which can take finite values except zero too. How to solve this question

Comment: Do you mean "let $f(x)$ be the minimum value of..."? Since the maximum value goes to infinity for any $x$: just pick very large $m,n$.

Comment: yes sorry mistyped it.

Comment: It seems that you have to prove that the numbers in form $\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}$ become more and more dense.

Comment: Hint: biggest m then biggest n

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x>1$. Let $m$ be the largest integer less than $x$. Let $a=x-m$. Let $n$ be the largest integer smaller than $\sqrt{ax}$. Let $b=\sqrt{ax}-n$. Note that $0\leq a,b\leq 1$.

$$m^2+2n^2=(x-a)^2+2(\sqrt{ax}-b)^2 =x^2+a^2+2b^2-4\sqrt{ax}b.$$

Subtracting $x^2$ and bounding it gives:
$$-4\sqrt{x}\leq a^2+2b^2-4\sqrt{ax}b\leq 1^2+2\cdot 1^2 -0=3\leq 4\sqrt{x}.$$

This simplifies to $|m^2+2n^2-x^2|\leq 4\sqrt{x}$.

Dividing by $|\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}+x|>x$ gives that:
$$f(x)\leq|\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}-x|\leq 4/\sqrt{x}.$$

Thus, as $x$ approaches $\infty$, $f(x)$ must approach $0$.

Comment: Couldn't understand $a^2+2b^2-4\sqrt {ax} b \le 3$ how to get it?

Comment: $a\leq 1$,$b\leq 1$, $-\sqrt{ax}b\leq 0$

Comment: Isn't it that equality sign should be removed because $a \to 1^- \; b \to 1^- $ and $\sqrt {ax} b \to 0$ would no hold simultaneously as you have assumed $x \gt 1$

Comment: I guess, but who cares? I don’t need the bound to be tight. As written, if $x$ is an integer then $m=x-1,a=1$ and it doesn’t really affect anything in the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Using a variant of [Gauss's Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem), we can prove that the limit is zero.

Let $N_x$ be the number of pairs of integers $(m,n)$ such that $m^2+2n^2\leq x^2$. Then
$$
N_x=\pi x^2/\sqrt 2 + O(x^{2/3}). 
$$
This gives for $\delta_x>0$,
$$
N_{x+\delta_x}-N_x=\pi((x+\delta_x)^2-x^2)/\sqrt2 + O(x^{2/3})
$$
$$
=\pi (2x\delta_x+\delta_x^2)/\sqrt2 +O(x^{2/3}).
$$
Thus if $\delta_x=x^{-1/3+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon>0$, it is guaranteed for sufficiently large $x$,
$$
N_{x+\delta_x}-N_x\geq 1. 
$$
Then for sufficiently large $x$, we have
$$
f(x)=\min|x-\sqrt{m^2+2n^2}|\leq \delta_x,
$$
yielding that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=0$.

Comment: Proving that the error term in Gauss’s Circle problem is $O(x^{2/3})$ seems fairly difficult  (Gauss’s initial bound was linear) and is way harder than the problem OP is asking about.

Comment: Yes, an elementary argument gives $O(x)$ which is not quite enough for proving $\lim f(x)=0$. But, I am curious to see any easier work around.

Comment: I added my own answer elaborating on my hint.